# How to add a test consumer to MassTransit configured to use LocalStack in an IntegrationTest

Tags: c#, testing, masstransit, localstack

I have MassTransit configured to use LocalStack for local development.  For integration testing, we have our tests setup to use Docker images of as many dependencies as possible to keep things as close to production as possible.

I have created a TestConsumer class.  If the WebApi project uses `AddConsumer<TestConsumer>()` as part of the `AddMassTransit(...)` call then the integration tests work just fine - using localstack.

But, the WebApi project should not be adding test stuff to production code.  Yes, I could have an if statement around the registration, but that is also bad practice (in my opinion).

I want the integration tests' `WebApplicationFactory.ConfigureWebHost(...)` method to tack on the consumer.  In my opinion, this is best because we don't have test code in the Api project.

MassTransit throws an error if you call `AddMassTransit(...)` more than once.  There is a `AddMassTransitTestHarness(...)` method, but that method removes all MassTransit configuration and replaces it with an in-memory queue - bypassing localstack.

I don't like this option because I want my integration tests to be as close as possible to production.  I could duplicate the registration in the `AddMassTransitTestHarness(...)` call, but that is just leading to potential bugs.  I could have some shared static methods which keeps the configuration is mostly one place, and if I can't find a better solution then I will end up going that route.

Does anyone know of a built in way to register a MassTransit consumer (and producer) in `WebApplicationFactory.ConfigureWebHost(...)` without re-doing all of the MassTransit registration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to add an adhoc consumer to your WebApplicationFactory you can look at trying something like this.

```cs
var client = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
  .WithWebHostBuilder(builder => 
  {
    builder.ConfigureServices(services => 
    {
      services.RegisterConsumer<AdHocTestConsumer>();
    });
  }).CreateDefaultClient();
```

That should get you what I believe you are looking for. Note that the extension method `RegisterConsumer` is in the namespace `MassTransit.Configuration`

Comment: This works, but not if you have custom topic names specified via `.SetEntityName` and `.Subscribe` - I couldn't figure out how to configure the `ReceiveEndpoint` outside of the MassTransit configuration.

It does work with default naming and with a `.SetEntityNameFormatter`